# Android-Openweathermap: list of cities after search

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, openweathermap

I'm just new to Android development and I'm trying to make a weather app where it shows list of countries with the city after making a search (ex. London). In openweathermap api, it shows 5 results with different countries with a name of "London" on it but in my codes it doesn't even show 1 result.

Here's my code:

```
public void getCityData(){
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    WeatherService weatherService = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);

    ListService listService = retrofit.create(ListService.class);


    String cityName = search.getEditableText().toString();

    stringArrayList.clear();
    stringArrayList.add(cityName);

    for (String city : stringArrayList) {
        Call<WeatherData> weatherDataCall = weatherService.getWeatherData("/data/2.5/find?q=" + city + "&APPID=" + API_KEY + "");
        weatherDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherData> call, Response<WeatherData> response) {
                ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(AddCityActivity.this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                WeatherData weatherData = response.body();
                List<cp2.openweatherv3.model.List> lists = weatherData.getList();

                for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++){
                    Log.d("name", lists.get(i).getName());
                    Log.e("country", lists.get(i).getSys().getCountry());
                    Log.w("count", String.valueOf(lists.size()));
                    generateList(lists);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherData> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("sometag", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(AddCityActivity.this, "not throwing anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I make it possible?

Thank you so much

Comment: are you getting response on onfailure method?

Comment: It only shows the toast that I made. How should I deal with it?

Comment: After few hours of observing the functionality, I think there are times where it does not work well, and times it works as I need it xD